# Select top 2 column sums and names

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the column sums, then select the top 2. This is a sample of the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(precinct = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 steve = c(309, 337, 294), 
                 mike = c(120, 151, 240), 
                 allan = c(379, 442, 597))
```

I know how to use `colSums` to get the column totals.

```
dfColTot <- colSums(df[ , 2:ncol(df)])
```

From there, how do you select the top 2 sums and names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
top_2=head(sort(dfColTot, decreasing=TRUE), 2)

top_2
#> allan steve 
#>  1418   940
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `order()`

```
df <- data.frame(precinct = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 steve = c(309, 337, 294), 
                 mike = c(120, 151, 240), 
                 allan = c(379, 442, 597))

dfColTot <- colSums(df[ , 2:ncol(df)])

head(dfColTot[order(dfColTot,decreasing = TRUE)],2)
```

The result is:

```
> head(dfColTot[order(dfColTot,decreasing = TRUE)],2)
allan steve 
 1418   940
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a dplyr option as well.

```
library(dplyr)

    df %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols=-precinct) %>%  #advisable to be it long format since summary is required by names.
      group_by(name) %>% 
      summarise(value=sum(value)) %>% #summation per name.
      ungroup() %>% 
      slice_max(order_by=value,n=2) # get the top2 based on descending value column
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 allan  1418
2 steve   940
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` and base R combination, if you do not want to have to pivot to long form. After summarizing the columns, I convert the row to a numeric list, then sort the the list and return the index number. I keep only the index number, `$ix`. Then, I sort and get the index of the top 2 values using `tail`. Then, I use the indices to select the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise(across(-precinct, sum)) %>%
  select(c(tail(
    sort(as.numeric(.[1, ]), index.return = TRUE)$ix, 2)))
```

**Output**

```
  steve allan
1   940  1418
```